# How to get the number of rows inserted and deleted by Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm writing a test driver that inserts a bunch of rows, runs some tests then deletes the rows that were inserted.  The rows in question form a tree of parent-child records.  For example the root of the tree is a document object that has a List attribute.  Each paragraph has a List attribute and so on for five levels of parent-child.

I'm inserting with Hibernate.  I build the document tree then pass the root object, a document, to Hibernate and the root and all children are inserted.

To remove the records I pass the root object to Hibernate.delete.

Is it possible to have Hibernate return the number of records inserted and deleted?

Answer (score 2):

You could try deleting using Hibernate.update. I found the following example at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_query_language.htm

```
String hql = "UPDATE Employee set salary = :salary "  + 
             "WHERE id = :employee_id";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("salary", 1000);
query.setParameter("employee_id", 10);
int result = query.executeUpdate();
System.out.println("Rows affected: " + result);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: should be noted this will return if a row was affected

Answer (score 0):

Work on in memory test database instead of your regular database. In this way your `@Before` and `@After` methods with take care of it.